# Reconnect View to View in Xcode 4

Tags: ios, xcode, view, xib, connection

How do you reconnect view to view in a xib in Xcode 4, where you accidentally deleted the view connection of the file's owner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the file's owner, amd simply reconnect the outlet to the view.

Comment: The view outlet does not show up at all... only the other objects show up

Comment: Oops - actually, ctrl-click connect wireframe box to dotted white box seems to set the View back to View.